# Inquiry on debugging an IIS web application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7

I developed a web application which is working perfectly on my local (laptop), now, when I copied-pasted the .dll (which came from my laptop) and other .aspx files on another PC and browsing the web application on the localhost (new machine), I am encountering an error saying Server error in "/" application,

Parser error message: Could not load type 'namespace.of.my.library'

Additional info:
When I build/publish the .dll, it's only producing one dll file, so I am sure that I didn't missed anything when I copy-pasted the code into a different machine.

I also checked the framework version of the generated dll and the framework version of IIS and they are the same with my laptop.

And since the web page is producing this error, I don't know how to debug, I can't get any relevant info out of it.

Did I missed something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you deployed the published website to IIS? If not try that.

Comment: Yes, I configured the web root of IIS on the same folder where those files were copied to.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a referenced assembly? Check that all your referenced assemblies are copied to the machine where you are having the problem.

Comment: Hi FatAlbert, Yes, I am using few referenced assemblies (i.e. System.Web.Services, System.Web, System.Data).  But how is that on my local laptop, these libraries were not existing on my web root and the web app is working as expected?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/906959.aspx/1

Comment: Try setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True in advanced settings of your application pool. Just a guess, but I've seen that error for that reason before several times.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delayed response.  I was so busy these past few days.  The link that FatAlbert posted fixed my issue.  It was a misconfiguration on my Web Site's Basic Settings.